# Filling in columns with certain columns from two dataframes in R

Tags: r, lapply

I have two dataframes(Ex: df1, df2). I would like to fill in one column(testing) from df1 to df2 conditioned on having the same ID and Name between the two dataframes. I have tried using a for-loop, but found it difficult to implement. The result should be as in the form: "output". I would appreciate your help. Thank you!

```
Code:
var_of_interest <- c("testing")
df2[var_of_interest] <- lapply(var_of_interest, function(x), df1[[x]][match(df2$ID, df1$ID) & match(df2$Name, df1$Name)])

df1: df1 is a subset of df2(It has information on testing)
ID Name testing
1  a    100
2  a    90
3  a    80
4  a    70
5  a    60

df2:
ID Name testing
1  a    NA
2  a    NA
2  b    400
3  a    NA
3  c    300
4  a    NA
4  d    200
5  a    NA
5  e    150


output:
ID Name testing
1  a    100
2  a    90
2  b    400
3  a    80
3  c    300
4  a    70
4  d    200
5  a    60
5  e    150
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options that might work for you

A base R approach

```
output <- merge(df1, df2, by = c('ID', 'Name'), all = TRUE)
output$testing <- ifelse(is.na(output$testing.x), output$testing.y, output$testing.x)
output <- subset(output, select = c(ID, Name, testing))
```

Or a `dplyr` approach

```
library(dplyr)

df2 %>% 
  left_join(df1, by = c('ID', 'Name')) %>%
  mutate(testing = coalesce(testing.x, testing.y)) %>%
  select(ID, Name, testing)
```

---

Edit: Based on the comment, a different approach to handle more variables. This approach makes use of `dplyr` and `tidyr`. The basic idea is to change the format of the data from "wide" (29 columns) to "long" (ID, Name, var, value_df1 and value_df2) where it is then easier to replace values.

I didn't test on a larger fake dataset, but I think this approach should work for an arbitrary number of variables.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 %>% 
  left_join(df1, by = c('ID', 'Name')) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c('ID', 'Name'),
               names_sep = '\\.',
               names_to = c('var', 'source')) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = source, values_from = value) %>%
  group_by(ID, Name, var) %>%
  mutate(value = coalesce(x, y)) %>%
  select(-x, -y) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = var, values_from = value)
```

Comment: Hi @nniloc. I was able to get it to work using the base R approach. However, if my df1 and df2 had more columns than the example above, is there a way for the output to have the same number of columns. For example, df1 has 29 variables/columns and df2 has 29 variables and columns. How can I get the output to get 29 variables/columns instead of 57 variables/columns(Assuming by ID and Name).